# Finding expectation value of position of a particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Consider the infinite potential well with energy eigenstates $|E_n\rangle$ and eigenvalues $E_n$ with $n = 1, 2, 3, . . .$

Suppose that the initial state is
$$|\psi(0)\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt{2}} (|E_1\rangle+\space |E_4\rangle)$$

Find $|x(t)]\rangle$.

Now what I have done is

$$|\psi(t)\rangle = \frac1{\sqrt{2}} (e^{-iE_1t/h}|E_1\rangle + e^{-iE_4t/h} |E_4]\rangle)$$
\begin{equation}
|x(t)\rangle\space =\space \langle\psi^{*}(x,t)|x|\psi(x,t)\rangle 
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \psi^{*}(x,t)\space x\space \psi(x,t)\space dx
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}[\frac1{\sqrt{2}} (e^{iE_1t/h}\langle E_1|+ e^{iE_4t/h}\langle E_4|)]\space x\space [\frac1{\sqrt{2}} (e^{-iE_1t/h}|E_1\rangle + e^{-iE_4t/h}|E_4\rangle )]
\end{equation}
Now
$$ \langle E_1|x|E_1\rangle \space = \space\langle E_4|x|E_4\rangle  = 0$$
But I can't figure our what to do with the following part
$$\langle E_4|x|E_1\rangle \space and \space\langle E_1|x|E_4\rangle  $$

I'm stuck here. I can solve the rest myself. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You forgot to mention that your box has $x=0$ at the center (so that $\langle n|x|n\rangle=0$). Many authors define the box as $[0, L]$, in which case:  $\langle n|x|n\rangle=L/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clear up the notation? What you wrote as $|{x(t)}\rangle$ is actually the expectation value of the position operator in the state $\psi(t)$. If that is what you are looking for: note that you have the expressions of the particle in a box eigenkets $|E_{n}\rangle$ in the position basis, given by the sine functions. The number $\langle E_{m}|x|E_{n}\rangle$ can be calculated as
\begin{align}
\langle E_{m}|x|E_{n}\rangle =\int dx \psi_{m}^{*}(x) x \psi_{n}(x) 
\end{align}
where you integrate along the width of the box.(can you show this?)

Comment: Explain a bit more please. I am still confused.

Comment: On notation, the n-th state should be written $|n\rangle$, so $n$ is an integer quantum number. Of course: $\hat H|n\rangle = E_n|n\rangle$, so that $E_n$ is a real number.

Comment: The wavefunctions of this system in the position basis are $\psi_{n}(x)= \sqrt{\frac{2}{L}} \sin (\frac{n \pi x}{L})$, where $L$ is the width of the box. The expression you have to calculate is the integral I have in my answer.
In response to @JEB, that would be the standard notation, but I was talking more about the fact that an expectation value is written as a ket.

Comment: You've shown the $\psi_n$ for the $[0, L]$ box, but the OP appears to be using the $[-L/2, +L/2]$ box.

Comment: Ah yes, that explains the vanishing expectation value for $n=m$.

Comment: So I use $\psi_n (x) = \sqrt{2/ L}sin(nπx/ L)$ to find $|E_1>$ and $|E_4>$ and then do the integration stuff. Is this what you are suggesting?

Comment: Yes but use the wavefunctions suitable for the $[-L/2, L/2]$ box.